# PySpark: add a row from one dataframe as a column with constant value to another dataframe

Tags: arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark dataframes:

```
>df1
+---------------+
|         values|
+---------------+
|[a, b, c, d, ..|
+---------------+

>df2
+---+---------+
| id|   number|
+---+---------+
|  1|    34523|
|  2|    56438|
|  5|    90342|
+---+---------+
```

How can I add column `values` from `df1` as constant value to each row in `df2`?
Expected output:

```
+---+---------+---------------+
| id|   number|         values|
+---+---------+---------------+
|  1|    34523|[a, b, c, d, ..|
|  2|    56438|[a, b, c, d, ..|
|  5|    90342|[a, b, c, d, ..|
+---+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, if its only one row, may as well just cross join. Please remember, this can be quite expensive if multiple rows are involved

```
df2.crossJoin(df1.select("values")).show()
```